# Alignedat with one different row

Tags: align, alignat

In the figure I attach, I'm ALMOST getting what I want. The problem is that, in the last line, the phrase "en otro caso" should start below the three "si". The thing is, in the first three lines there are three columns in each line, but the last one has only two. How can I distribute the &'s so as to get what I want? Here is the code:

```
\begin{alignat*}{3}
    &\frac{\mu_\off l_\on^{\nicefrac{1}{\alpha_\on}}}{\left(\mu_\on+\mu_\off\right)^{1+\nicefrac{1}{\alpha_\on}}} S_{\alpha_\on,\sigma,1}(t)& \quad &\text{si}& \quad &\alpha_\on<\alpha_\off \ , \ \alpha_\on<2 \ ,\\
    &\frac{\mu_\on l_\off^{\nicefrac{1}{\alpha_\off}}}{\left(\mu_\on+\mu_\off\right)^{1+\nicefrac{1}{\alpha_\off}}} S_{\alpha_\off,\sigma,-1}(t)& \quad &\text{si}& \quad &\alpha_\off<\alpha_\on \ , \ \alpha_\on<2 \ ,\\
    &\frac{\left(\mu_\off^\alpha l_\on+\mu_\on^\alpha l_\off\right)^{\nicefrac{1}{\alpha}}}{\left(\mu_\on+\mu_\off\right)^{1+\nicefrac{1}{\alpha}}} S_{\alpha,\sigma,\beta}(t)& \quad &\text{si}& \quad &\alpha=\alpha_\on=\alpha_\off<2 \ ,\\
    &\frac{\left[\left(\mu_\off\sigma_\on\right)^2+\left(\mu_\on\sigma_\off\right)^2\right]^{\nicefrac{1}{2}}}{\left(\mu_\on+\mu_\off\right)^{\nicefrac{3}{2}}}B(t)& \quad &&&\text{en otro caso.}
\end{alignat*}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you want `en otro caso` to be centred in the last two columns, ar aligned with `si`?

Comment: Thanks! Aligned with `si` if possible

Comment: That's easy, if I know what are the `\on` and `\off` macros. You should always check your code is compilable as is.

Comment: You can use `\mathrlap{\text{en otro caso}}` aligned at the same `&` as the "si"s.  The `\mathrlap` makes latex think this has zero width, so it won't affect the alignment.  (Requires `mathtools`.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: No mathtools required (albeit recommended), since the argument of a plain `\rlap` is in text mode.

Comment: @Bernard You're right, I'm sorry. The commands are `\newcommand{\on}{\text{\emph{on}}\xspace}`and `\newcommand{\off}{\text{\emph{off}}\xspace}`. Should I add it to the post?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: I don't think so, since your problem is solved with @barbarabeeton 's comment. Unrelated: I think `on` and  `off`, which are ordinary text words  used in a formula, not variables, should be in upshape.

Comment: Hmm I just emphasize them because they are in a language (English) different from the one of the whole document (Spanish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exploit symmetries:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

\newcommand{\off}{{\mathrm{off}}}
\newcommand{\on}{{\mathrm{on}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
&\frac{\mu_\off l_\on^{1/\alpha_\on}}{(\mu_\on+\mu_\off)^{1+1/\alpha_\on}}
 S_{\alpha_\on,\sigma,1}(t)
&\qquad&
  \text{si} \quad \alpha_\on<\alpha_\off \ , \ \alpha_\on<2 \ ,
\\
&\frac{\mu_\on l_\off^{1/\alpha_\off}}{(\mu_\on+\mu_\off)^{1+1/\alpha_\off}}
 S_{\alpha_\off,\sigma,-1}(t)
&\qquad&
  \text{si} \quad \alpha_\off<\alpha_\on \ , \ \alpha_\on<2 \ ,
\\
&\frac{(\mu_\off^\alpha l_\on+\mu_\on^\alpha l_\off)^{1/\alpha}}
      {(\mu_\on+\mu_\off)^{1+1/\alpha}}
 S_{\alpha,\sigma,\beta}(t)
&\qquad&
  \text{si} \quad \alpha=\alpha_\on=\alpha_\off<2 \ ,
\\
&\frac{\bigl[(\mu_\off\sigma_\on)^2+(\mu_\on\sigma_\off)^2\bigr]^{1/2}}
 {(\mu_\on+\mu_\off)^{3/2}}
 B(t)
&\qquad&
  \text{en otro caso.}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Reinstate your `\uglyfrac` (oh, it's named `\nicefrac`, but it's a wrong name ) if you really want. I removed also all `\left` and `\right` that lead to oversized fences. The words “on” and “off” should be in upright type, regardless whether they are from a foreign language: they're used with a specified meaning, so they should be considered standard words.

[image]

Comment: That's actually a much simpler solution. Thanks for that!